# Как сделать проверку на существование класса который добавляется по событию?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всех с Новым Годом! подскажите пожалуйста как сделать проверку существует ли класс. сейчас делаю так
`if ( $("#morf").hasClass("active") ) {
alert('yes');
}`

класс active добавляется на событие скролл. а функция hasClass находит классы только если они есть в html. Подскажите как можно сделать проверку на добавленный класс.

Comment: Запустить приведенный код после того как класс был добавлен/изменен/удален. Например на том же событии `scroll`. Но это совсем плохо с точки зрения производительности, поэтому лучше проверяйте там где Вам нужно

Comment: и на тостере успели)))

Comment: да)) спасибо большое за помощь